# Creación de matriz a partir de los datos de un vector en python

Tags: python

Trabajo en un ejercicio en el cual me pide que cree un vector y a partir de los datos de ese vector, que lo transforme en una matriz.
El problema que tengo es que no se como mandar esos números del vector a la matriz y también creo que esta mal la funcion crear matriz inversa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Primera cosa, el código como texto. Una foto de código no es de utilidad.

Comment: a bueno genial no me di cuenta,ahora lo edito.